# How can use javascript 'onclick' event in xml file?

Tags: javascript, xml, onclick, jwplayer

I've an xml file which has some codes like :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
            <layout>
                <group position="left">
                    <button name="play" />
                    <text name="elapsed" />
                </group>
                <group position="center">
                    <slider name="time" />
                </group>
                <group position="right">
                    <text name="duration" />
                    <button name="blank" />
                    <button name="mute" />
                </group>
            </layout>
```

I want to add onclick event to the 'play' button, so I tried-

```
<button name="play" onclick="test();" />
<button name="play" onclick="alert('ok');" />
<button name="play" onclick="javascript:test();" />
```

but none of those worked. how should I use onclick event there ?

-Thanks.

***Edit :***
I'm using jwplayer 5.2 pro and the xml file is for the player skin.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<skin version="1.1" name="Glow" author="LongTail Video">

    <components>
        <component name="controlbar">
            <settings>
                <setting name="margin" value="0" />
                <setting name="fontsize" value="11" />
                <setting name="fontcolor" value="0xEEEEEE" />
                <setting name="buttoncolor" value="0xEEEEEE" />
                                <setting name="backgroundcolor" value="0x990000" />
            </settings>

            <layout>
                <group position="left">
                    <button name="play" />
                    <text name="elapsed" />
                </group>
                <group position="center">
                    <slider name="time" />
                </group>
                <group position="right">
                    <text name="duration" />
                    <button name="blank" />
                    <button name="mute" />
                </group>
            </layout>

            <elements>
                <element name="background" src="background.png" />
                <element name="blankButton" src="blankButton.png" />
                <element name="fullscreenButton" src="fullscreenButton.png" />
                <element name="fullscreenButtonOver" src="fullscreenButtonOver.png" />
                <element name="muteButton" src="muteButton.png" />
                <element name="muteButtonOver" src="muteButtonOver.png" />
                <element name="pauseButton" src="pauseButton.png" />
                <element name="pauseButtonOver" src="pauseButtonOver.png" />
                <element name="playButton" src="playButton.png" />
                <element name="playButtonOver" src="playButtonOver.png" />
                <element name="timeSliderBuffer" src="timeSliderBuffer.png" />
                <element name="timeSliderCapLeft" src="timeSliderCapLeft.png" />
                <element name="timeSliderCapRight" src="timeSliderCapRight.png" />
                <element name="timeSliderProgress" src="timeSliderProgress.png" />
                <element name="timeSliderRail" src="timeSliderRail.png" />
                <element name="normalscreenButton" src="normalscreenButton.png" />
                <element name="normalscreenButtonOver" src="normalscreenButtonOver.png" />
                <element name="unmuteButton" src="unmuteButton.png" />
                <element name="unmuteButtonOver" src="unmuteButtonOver.png" />
            </elements>
        </component>

        <component name="display">
            <settings>
                <setting name="bufferinterval" value="250" />
                <setting name="bufferrotation" value="90" />
            </settings>
            <elements>
                <element name="background" src="background.png" />
                <element name="playIcon" src="playIcon.png" />
                <element name="muteIcon" src="muteIcon.png" />
                <element name="bufferIcon" src="bufferIcon.png" />
            </elements>
        </component>

        <component name="dock">
            <elements>
                <element name="button" src="button.png" />
                <element name="buttonOver" src="button.png" />
            </elements>
        </component>

        <component name="playlist">
            <settings>
                <setting name="fontcolor" value="0xEEEEEE" />
                <setting name="backgroundcolor" value="0x333333" />
            </settings>
            <elements>
                <element name="item" src="item.png" />
                <element name="itemOver" src="itemOver.png" />
                <element name="sliderCapBottom" src="sliderCapBottom.png" />
                <element name="sliderCapTop" src="sliderCapTop.png" />
                <element name="sliderRail" src="sliderRail.png" />
                <element name="sliderThumb" src="sliderThumb.png" />
            </elements>
        </component>

    </components>

</skin>
```

and the html :

```
<object id="player1" width="300" height="35" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0">
    <param name="flashvars" value="" />
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
    <param name="src" value="jwplayer/player.swf" />
    <embed id="player1" width="300" height="35" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="jwplayer/player.swf" flashvars="skins=autostart=true&skin=jwplayer/skins/skin1.zip" allowscriptaccess="always" />
</object>
```

Comment: What exactly are you *doing* with this XML file? How do you expect it to be clicked anyways?

Comment: @Wesley My words exactly!

Comment: sorry, I'm using jwplayer 5.2 pro. so xml file is used there for the player. please see my edit.

Comment: Do you have an example of where you tried this, as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality of elements in JWPlayer skins is defined based on the name of the button. You cannot attach extra Javascript to elements in the XML.

If you want to add custom buttons to the player, you can do this using the JWPlayer Javascript API. Please refer to:

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/29404/video-download-button